# How to allow cross origin redirection to another url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, spotify

I'm trying to set the access_token in the first render, so I made a get request from the front-end to the /login route. When I run it, however, I get a CORS error that says: Cross origin redirection to {url} denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 303.

This is what my login route looks like in Express.

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log('logging in 3');
  const scope = [
    'ugc-image-upload',
    'user-read-playback-state',
    'user-modify-playback-state',
    'user-read-currently-playing',
    'streaming',
    'app-remote-control',
    'user-read-email',
    'user-read-private',
    'playlist-read-collaborative',
    'playlist-modify-public',
    'playlist-read-private',
    'playlist-modify-private',
    'user-library-modify',
    'user-library-read',
    'user-top-read',
    'user-read-playback-position',
    'user-read-recently-played',
    'user-follow-read',
    'user-follow-modify'
  ];
  const state = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2,18);

  const auth_query_parameters = new URLSearchParams({
    response_type: "code",
    client_id: client_id,
    scope: scope,
    redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
    state: state
  });
  
  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' + 
  auth_query_parameters.toString());
});
```

This is what my React code looks like.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const refresh_token = Cookies.get('refresh_token');
  
    setAccessToken(Cookies.get('access_token'));

    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/login')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
}, [])

I tried things like using the cors library from the backend and also using a proxy, but I still seem to get this error. What do I do?
```

Comment: You can't do anything. The spotify URL doesn't allow cors, so you can't fetch it from your browser. The fact that you fetch from you backend that then redirect to spotify doesn't matter. It's still a CORS violation.

Comment: is the `axios.get('http://localhost:3001/login')` request same or cross origin? cors library won't help if you just redirect - show how you tried to proxy the request, that should work